# Output of a beamsplitter with photon number (Fock) state inputs

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, quantum-computer, quantum-optics

Given a beamsplitter drawn below, where $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ are input modal annihilation operators, transmissivity is $\tau\in[0,1]$, and output modal annihilation operators are $\hat{c}=\sqrt{\tau}\hat{a}+\sqrt{1-\tau}\hat{b}$ and $\hat{d}=\sqrt{1-\tau}\hat{a}+\sqrt{\tau}\hat{b}$, suppose the inputs $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ are in photon number (Fock) states $|m\rangle$ and $|n\rangle$, respectively.  What are the states of the outputs $\hat{c}$ and $\hat{d}$?

[image: beamsplitter]

I understand that if one of the inputs is a vacuum state $|0\rangle$, then the output states are binomial mixtures of photon number states, with "probability of success" parameter being either $\tau$ or $1-\tau$ and the "number of trials" parameter being the photon number $n$ of the non-vacuum input (so, if $|0\rangle$ was input on mode $\hat{a}$ and $|n\rangle$ on mode $\hat{b}$, then mode $\hat{c}$ is in the state $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(1-\tau)^k\tau^{n-k}|k\rangle$ and mode $\hat{d}$ is in the state $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\tau^k(1-\tau)^{n-k}|k\rangle$).  I am wondering how this generalizes to both input modes being in the non-vacuum states.

Comment: And if you put in one photon at each input for a 50-50 beam splitter, two come out of one output and none the other output.

Comment: @PeterShor What makes you say that ?

Comment: It's the [Hong](http://spie.org/Documents/ETOP/2013/1_General%20Concepts/ETOP2013_1-07.pdf)-[Ou](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld2r2IMt4vg)-[Mandel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong–Ou–Mandel_effect) effect.

Comment: Unfortunately, my case isn't as simple as HOM effect... beamsplitter not necessarily 50-50 and arbitrary number of photons can be at either input...

Comment: @M.B.M.: using the same idea as in the HOM effect, it's easy to calculate for one photon at each input, and an arbitrary beam splitter: 2 out of one output with probability $2\tau(1-\tau)$; one from each output with probability $(1-2\tau)^2$. It gets more complicated when you have larger input photon numbers. [See this paper](http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.40.1371). [Also this one](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-0847-8_26). [Available here with no pay wall](http://people.bu.edu/teich/pdfs/PRA-40-1371-1989.pdf).

Comment: I think you should have a minus sign somewhere because your matrix ($\hat c,\hat d  $function of $\hat a, \hat b$) is not unitary.

Comment: Following @PeterShor advices, and correcting the minus sign problem, you just invert the matrix to express $\hat a , \hat b$ function of $\hat c , \hat d$. The matrix is real, so it works for creation operators transformation too. With one particle in $a$, and one particle in $b$, you will get, (up maybe to some amplitude sign) , $a^+b^+ = \sqrt{\tau(1-\tau)}((d^+)^2 - (c^+)^2) - (2\tau-1)c^+d^+$.

Comment: @PeterShor Looks like equation (48a) in the reference you provided is what I need -- thanks!  Looks complicated indeed.

Comment: I don't think your statement, when mode a is vacuum the mode c is in that state, is correct. That's under the situation that the original state is a tensor product of $n$ single photon state, where the $n$ photons are unrelated with each other, instead of Fock state, where $n$ photons are related and inseparable. Actually, I'm trying to use the formula below to calculate the photon number distribution. But it's too trivial. Maybe we can talk about this and share some experience. $$P_n=Tr(\rho :(c^+c)^n/n! e^{-c^+c}:)$$

Answer (score 7):

The transformation equations you specify are not correct since they do not respect unitarity. The condition of unitarity (or energy conservation) for the action of the beam-splitter gives the following transformations:

$\hat{c}=\sqrt{\tau}\hat{a}+\sqrt{1-\tau}\hat{b}$

$\hat{d}=\sqrt{1-\tau}\hat{a}-\sqrt{\tau}\hat{b}$

The minus sign in the second equation ensures that unitarity is respected.

For reasons that will become clear soon, let us invert these equations to get the input mode operators $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ in terms of the output mode operators $\hat{c}$ and $\hat{d}$. As expected from arguments of reversibility, we get:

$\hat{a}=\sqrt{\tau}\hat{c}+\sqrt{1-\tau}\hat{d}$

$\hat{b}=\sqrt{1-\tau}\hat{c}-\sqrt{\tau}\hat{d}$

It is useful to look at this problem in the Heisenberg picture where the action of the beam-splitter is entirely on the mode creation and annihilation operators with initial field state being assumed as vacuum.

Since the input states being considered are the Fock states $|m\rangle_{a}$ and $|n\rangle_{b}$ the full intial field state can alternatively be written as:

${(a^{\dagger})^m(b^{\dagger})^n |0\rangle_{a}|0\rangle_{b}|0\rangle_{c}|0\rangle_{d}}$

Now we substitute the earlier expressions for $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ in terms of $\hat{c}$ and $\hat{d}$ given by the beam-splitter transformations. The field state after the mode transformations is,

$(\sqrt{\tau}\hat{c}^{\dagger}+\sqrt{1-\tau}\hat{d}^{\dagger})^m(\sqrt{1-\tau}\hat{c}^{\dagger}-\sqrt{\tau}\hat{d}^{\dagger})^n|0\rangle_{a}|0\rangle_{b}|0\rangle_{c}|0\rangle_{d}$

Thus the output states for a beam-splitter transformation on input Fock states have been obtained.

As Peter Shor correctly pointed out, a beautiful consequence of these transformations is the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect. It states that when single-photon states are incident at the same time on the input ports of the beam-splitter, both photons emerge from the same output port.

This may be verified easily from the equation we have obtained by putting $m=n=1$. Also for convenience let us put $\tau=0.5$ i.e the beam-splitter is $50:50$ ratio. The output field state is,

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{c}^{\dagger}+\hat{d}^{\dagger})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{c}^{\dagger}-\hat{d}^{\dagger})|0\rangle_{a}|0\rangle_{b}|0\rangle_{c}|0\rangle_{d}$

$=\frac{1}{2}\big((\hat{c}^{\dagger})^2-(\hat{d}^{\dagger})^2\big)|0\rangle_{a}|0\rangle_{b}|0\rangle_{c}|0\rangle_{d}$

$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|2\rangle_{c}|0\rangle_{d}-|0\rangle_{c}|2\rangle_{d})$

Thus, we clearly see that either both photons emerge from port $C$ or both emerge from port $D$. Such a state is referred to as a two-photon NOON state (the state looks like that when N=2) and this effect is of paramount importance in linear optical quantum computing schemes.